# Como aplicar borda numa tabela sem o atributo "border"?

Tags: html, css, css3

Comecei a estudar HTML a pouco mais de uma semana e hoje encontrei um problema. Se bem me recordo, o atributo "border" não é mais utilizado na hora de colocar bordas numa tabela html. Tentei aplicar usando CSS (usando "border-width") mas não funcionou. Existe algum modo rápido de aplicar essa borda sem utilizar o border?

Answer (score 0):

Se vc colocou apenas o "border-width" realmente não irá aparecer, vc precisa definir tbm o estilo e a cor da borda, da seguinte forma:

```
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
```

Ou de forma abreviada:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

E caso queira retirar os espaços entre as bordas utilize:

```
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
```

Answer (score -1):

Para adicionar a borda a uma tabela usa-se a seguinte regra. Podes definir a espessura, o tipo e a cor.

```
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```